# Is it possible to boot Linux from Raw partition?

Tags: linux, filesystems, freebsd

I have a FreeBSD box running on x86_64. Box have 1 TB of HDD with 9 partition out of which 8 are formatted in UFS2 and one is raw partition (200 GB ). FreeBSD running currently do not have ext2 support enabled. Linux do not have UFS RW support.

I'm working under following constraints:
a) I cannot upgrade to BSD version with ext2 support. 
b) I cannot change partition table as that will lead to potential data loss
c) Box do not have NFS or USB support.

As far as I know to boot Linux my root should be ext2. Curious to know if it is possible to boot Linux on this box given above conditions.

Comment: What's your raw partition used for? If its unused, can't you just put a Linux-supported FS on it?

Comment: @derobert How you format raw? We can only format raw in FS supported by both OS. Other then ext2 I don't know any other shared FS.

Comment: FAT aka msdosfs?

Comment: @arrowd Correct.  It seems Fat32 do not support symbolic links. So not sure if linux will bot from fat32 partition.  I tried once. When I untared linux distroot into fat 32 partition the size of distroot was much smaller then on ext2 partition. later on booting I got kernel panic.